# Unsure if this asynchronous D-Flip-Flop Verilog code makes sense

Tags: verilog, flipflop

This is my code for an async-reset-set D-flip-flop. I'm using quartus, and the module compiles, but there is no way to check if my logic is valid. I could use some outside opinions.

The reset is asynchronous (1=reset) and set is represented by enable.

Here is my code:

```
module DFF_async(in, enable, clock, reset, out);
    input in, enable, clock, reset;
    output out;
    reg out;

    always @ (posedge clock or posedge reset)
        if(reset) begin
            out <= 1'b0;
        end else if (enable) begin
            out <= in;
        end 
endmodule
```

Comment: You need to write a test bench to verify your design

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is valid. There is no problem to use other signals as conditions inside a combinational or sequential process.

Just one remark though. You say it is asynchronous because of the reset signal, right? You know the enable will only be checked in a rising edge of the clock, do you?

Additionally, I agree with Plutonium Smuggler. If you want to verify your design, you should probably write a test bench and look at its behavior in a simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code functionally ok. It will be better if you use self explanatory labels. And use minimum code as possible.

> module DFF_async(D, clock, reset, Q);
>       input D, clock, reset;
>       output Q;
>       reg Q;
>
> ```
> always @ (posedge clock, reset)
>     if(reset) 
>         Q <= 1'b0;        else 
>         Q <= D; endmodule
> ```

Comment: Hmm, there is optimising code into fewer lines, but removing all of the 'begin' and 'end' statements only serves to make the code harder to follow and more prone to errors. Writing begin and end doesn't take very long and it is a good habit to get into.